# Syntax highlighting hint is ignored in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, syntax-highlighting

I recently asked [a Ruby-related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309015/why-am-i-getting-a-nomethoderror-when-using-the-google-api-to-run-a-query-agains). I added a stack trace of my error in a code block, and added the comment hint `language: lang-none` to disable syntax highlighting for the stack trace. However, when I went to check the question's status on SE Android app (v1.0.51), the Ruby syntax highlighting had reappeared.

Comment: [Link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309015/why-am-i-getting-a-nomethoderror-when-using-the-google-api-to-run-a-query-agains) -- Happens on the newest app version (1.0.33) too.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thank you, for Linking to the question.

Comment: still happens in 1.0.34 too.

Comment: Still happens in 1.0.51

Comment: Still happens in 1.0.83

Comment: Still happens in 1.0.85

Comment: The operator **animuson** has [just told me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279142/stack-overflow-syntax-highlighting-bug-on-android-application?noredirect=1#comment904382_279142) in a comment (on my question which he closed as being a duplicate of this one) that **Kasra Rahjerdi** is the author of the Android app. That puts a completely different light on [his comment above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230670/syntax-highlighting-hint-is-ignored-in-android-app#comment757996_230670) whcih was made over two years ago now

Comment: @Borodin he's not the author. He's the team leader, and the team is now only one person.