# Stack Overflow Syntax Highlighting Bug on Android Application

Tags: bug, markdown, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering, android

***Update*** I am now seeing that the text is being coloured correctly on my PC system and the issue seems to be only with the Android application. Either the issue is an intermittent one or I was simply mistaken

I edited [this Perl question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37092972/622310) with a syntax highlight hint like this

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

with the intention of removing all highlighting from something that is essentially plain text

On both my tablet and my Linux PC, despite a forced reload, I can still see some words highlighted in a dull green. At the time of writing, the words `Homo` and `RefSeq` are highlighted in green if they appear in code blocks with a `lang-none` tag

Perl highlighting has always been dreadful, and deserves a bug report of its own if it doesn't have one already, but I have never known the highlighter to ignore hints like this

Can someone please confirm that they see the same thing as I do, and perhaps explain why it is like that?

This screenshot from my tablet shows the problem clearly

[image: Here's a cropped screenshot from my tablet]

Comment: To whoever closed this post, doesn't it say "this question already has an answer here"? The question that you linked to has no answers at all, and is a poorer expression of the problem than my own post. Too much responsibility perhaps?

Comment: The pictorial evidence is not necessary. There's already a comment there from the Android App developer that he knows this happens - it just hasn't been fixed yet. Meta does not require duplicates have answers, and the yellow boxes here both say "this is an exact duplicate" with no mention of answers.

Comment: @animuson: Thank you. I can see none of that information from this app.

Comment: @animuson: I cannot see a comment from anyone saying that that they're aware that this happens. There is just a trail of comments saying "this still doesn't work on my version". Please help me find the comment you're referring to

Comment: It's the very first comment on that question, from Kasra, with the diamond on his name. He's the Android App developer, and has confirmed that it happens.

Comment: @animuson: While *you* may know that Kasra Rahjerdi is the author of the Android app, to everyone else his comment *"Happens on the newest app version (1.0.33) too"* is just another subscriber saying "me too". It's followed by three pretty much identical posts and then mine, so it hasn't been fixed for two years now