# Syntax highlighting does not turn off on mobile app

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, mobile-app

Take this example code block:

```
In [1]: text = "I'm a stringy!"

In [2]: print(text)
I'm a stringy!

In [3]: print(text[:-1])
I'm a stringy

In [4]: print(text[::-1])
!ygnirts a m'I

In [5]: print(text[:4:-1])

In [6]: print((text:4:-1] + text[:3:5])[::-1])
I stringy!

In [7]: print(text[::-1][::-1][::-1])
!ygnirts a m'I
```

The quotes start a red portion even if `<!-- language: lang-none -->` is at the top. I expected fully non-colored text.

---

On iOS:

> [image: IOS screenshot]

And Android:

> [image: Android screenshot]

Comment: What app? iOS or android?

Comment: iOS for sure. Just tested it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Android, version 5

Comment: @PatrickHofman so the bug is on IOS too?

Comment: Added a screenshot. You might want to add one for Android too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have taken it but I have trouble adding an image to the post on mobile....

Comment: @PatrickHoffman I authorize you all to add the image in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxW2x7KJABOAdXpZdmRLYzdwS2s/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: @PatrickHofman Wow, thanks for being so fast & responsive, this is the heaven of bug-report handling.

Comment: Dupe for Android: [Syntax highlighting hint is ignored in Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230670/syntax-highlighting-hint-is-ignored-in-android-app)